# Cast from class name

Tags: c++, qt, casting

How cast the pointer `this` from a class name?
`this` is a pointer on object which inherit form `QObject`.

I tried `metaObject->cast(this)` but how get a QMetaObject from a class name?

**EDIT**
I have a class `Node`

> ```
> class Node : public QObject
> {
> Q_OBJECT
> public:
> Node(QObject* p = NULL):QObject(p){}
> virtual void runImplementation() = 0;
> void run() 
> {
>     //initialize all input properties        
>     ...        
>     runImplementation();
> }
> void setInputValue(QMap<QString, QVariant> inputsValue) { _inputsValue = inputsValue;}
> private:
> QMap<QString, QVariant> _inputsValue;
> };
> ```

the class `NodeA`

> ```
> class NodeA : public Node 
> {
> Q_OBJECT
> Q_PROPERTY(int _a READ a WRITE setA)
> public:
> NodeA(QObject* p = NULL): Node (p){}
> void runImplementation() {//do specific operation}
> int a() const { return _a;}
> void setA(int a) { _a = a;}
> private:
> int _a;
> };
> ```

and a class `NodeB`

> ```
> class NodeB : public NodeA
> {
> Q_OBJECT
> Q_PROPERTY(double _a READ a WRITE setA)
> public:
> NodeB(QObject* p = NULL):NodeA(p){}
> void runImplementation() {//do specific operation}
> double a() const { return _a;}
> void setA(double a) { _a = a;}
> private:
> double _a;
> };
> ```

In the method `run` I would like initialize all input properties with value contained in the map.

> ```
> NodeB nodeB;
> QMap<QString, QVariant> inputB;
> QVariant varDouble;
> varDouble.setValue(5.4);
> inputB.insert(QString("_a"), varDouble);
> QVariant varInt;
> varInt.setValue(3);
> inputB.insert(QString("NodeA:_a"), varInt);
> nodeB.setInputValue(inputB);
> nodeB.run();
> ```

So in the `run` method I iterate on the map and,

- I would like cast the pointer `this` in the real type of my object
  (`NodeB`). This is my first problem. With this I can access to the
  property `double _a`. For the moment I do this with `QVariant v = this->metaObject()->cast(this)->property(...);` But is it the good ?
- and I would like cast the pointer `this` in the type (`NodeA`). This
  is my second problem. With this I can access to the property `int
  _a`.

Comment: There is no one to one mapping between class name and objects (QMetaObjects). There can be many object of the same class.

Comment: Ask you question properly, give some example what are you doing. Casting based on class name in `QString` has no point. Maybe you need operate on meta data, no casting.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? That is, what problem are you trying to solve by casting `this`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `static_cast<NodeA*>(this)` or `dynamic_cast<NodeA*>(this)`, but you **MUST NOT** do that. Because the base class can never know that it's actually an instance of the derived. Instead use your virtual method `runImplementation` to initialize classes inherited from `Node`.

Good initialization will look like this:

```
NodeB b;
b.load(map);

class NodeB
{
   virtual void load(QVariantMap map) override
   {
     loadMyself(map);
     NodeA::load(map); // or even better: NodeA::load(map["base"].toMap());
   }
}

class NodeA
{
   virtual void load(QVariantMap map) override
   {
     loadMyself(map);
     Node::load(map); // or even better: Node::load(map["base"].toMap());
   }
}

class Node
{
   virtual void load(QVariantMap map)
   {
     loadMyself(map);
   }
}
```

EDIT:

**Initialization of Qt properties**
To access Qt properties you don't need to have a pointer to a class instance where a real property is added.
Just use `this->property("_a")` or `this->property("_b")` BUT property names should be unique. When you declare property `_a` in `NodeB` you override property `_a` in `NodeA` and it become inaccessible anymore through Qt meta system.

Comment: Yes, but all method `loadMyself` will be the same.                 >   virtual void loadMyself(QMap<QString, QVariant>map) override { for(QMap<QString, QVariant>::iterator it = map.begin() ; it != map.end() ; ++it) { QVariant prop = this->property(it->key); if(prop.isValid() && prop.typ() == it->value().type()){setProperty(it->key().toStdString().c_str(), it->value());}}}

Comment: @artoon Added information about Qt properties in my answer